# error while training the generator in a text to image gan model

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a gan model which takes text embeddings and transforms them into an image due to a lack of resources I loaded the generator in GPU and discriminator in CPU.
and I deleted every variable I do not further need in the training loop and then cleared the memory.
this is my train function :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.utils import save_image
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tqdm import tqdm

def train_gan(generator, discriminator, dataset, batch_size, num_epochs, device):
    
    # Set up loss functions and optimizers
    adversarial_loss_generator = nn.BCELoss()
    adversarial_loss_discriminator=nn.BCELoss()
    generator_optimizer = optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    discriminator_optimizer = optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    
    # Set up data loader
    data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    generator.to(device)
    discriminator.to("cpu")
    
    # Train the GAN
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, data in enumerate(tqdm(data_loader)):
            # Load data and labels onto the device
            text_embeddings = data['text_embedding'].to(device)            
            # Generate fake images using the generator and the text embeddings
            noise = torch.randn(batch_size,generator.latent_dim).to(device)
            fake_images = generator(text_embeddings,noise)
            del noise
            clear_memory()
            fake_images = F.interpolate(fake_images, size=(512, 512), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
            # Train the discriminator
            discriminator_optimizer.zero_grad()
            real_images = data['image'].to("cpu")
            real_labels = torch.ones(real_images.size(0), 1).to("cpu")
            
            text_embeddings=text_embeddings.to("cpu")
            real_predictions = discriminator(real_images, text_embeddings)
            del real_images
            clear_memory()
            real_predictions=real_predictions.to("cpu")
            real_labels= real_labels.to("cpu")
            real_loss = adversarial_loss_discriminator(real_predictions, real_labels)
            real_loss=real_loss.to("cpu")
            fake_images=fake_images.to("cpu")
            text_embeddings=text_embeddings.to("cpu")
            fake_predictions = discriminator(fake_images, text_embeddings)
            fake_predictions=fake_predictions.to("cpu")
            fake_labels = torch.zeros(fake_images.size(0), 1).to("cpu")
            fake_loss = adversarial_loss_discriminator(fake_predictions, fake_labels)
            del fake_labels
            clear_memory()
            fake_loss=fake_loss.to ("cpu")
            discriminator_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
            discriminator_loss=discriminator_loss.to("cpu")
            discriminator_loss.backward()
            discriminator_optimizer.step()
            
            # Train the generator
            generator_optimizer.zero_grad()
            #fake_predictions = discriminator(fake_images, text_embeddings)
            del text_embeddings
            del fake_images
            clear_memory()
            fake_predictions=fake_predictions.to(device)
            real_labels=real_labels.to(device)
            
            generator_loss = adversarial_loss_generator(fake_predictions, real_labels)
            generator_loss=generator_loss.to(device)
            generator_loss.backward()
            generator_optimizer.step()
            del fake_predictions
            del real_labels
            clear_memory()

            # Save generated images and model checkpoints every 500 batches
            if i % 100 == 0:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    noise = torch.randn(batch_size,generator.latent_dim).to("cpu")
                    text_embeddings = data['text_embedding'].to("cpu")            
                    fake_images = generator(noise,text_embeddings)
                save_image(fake_images, f"images\generated_images_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.png", normalize=True, nrow=4)
                torch.save(generator.state_dict(), f"models\generator_checkpoint_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.pt")
                torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), f"models\discriminator_checkpoint_epoch_{epoch}_batch_{i}.pt")
                
        # Print loss at the end of each epoch
        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}] Discriminator Loss: {discriminator_loss.item()}, Generator Loss: {generator_loss.item()}")
```

and for  the function of clearing the memory

```
import gc
def clear_memory():
    gc.collect()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

in the backward pass for the generator I get the following error

```
in <module>:1                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│ ❱ 1 train_gan(generator=generator,                                                               │
│   2 │   │     discriminator=discriminator,                                                       │
│   3 │   │     dataset=dataset,                                                                   │
│   4 │   │     batch_size=batch_size,                                                             │
│                                                                                                  │
│ in train_gan:71                                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│   68 │   │   │                                                                                   │
│   69 │   │   │   generator_loss = adversarial_loss_generator(fake_predictions, real_labels)      │
│   70 │   │   │   generator_loss=generator_loss.to(device)                                        │
│ ❱ 71 │   │   │   generator_loss.backward()                                                       │
│   72 │   │   │   generator_optimizer.step()                                                      │
│   73 │   │   │   del fake_predictions                                                            │
│   74 │   │   │   del real_labels                                                                 │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\Users\Mohamed Amine\Desktop\pytorch_env\torchvenv\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py:221 in    │
│ backward                                                                                         │
│                                                                                                  │
│    218 │   │   │   │   gradient=gradient,                                                        │
│    219 │   │   │   │   retain_graph=retain_graph,                                                │
│    220 │   │   │   │   create_graph=create_graph)                                                │
│ ❱  221 │   │   torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)               │
│    222 │                                                                                         │
│    223 │   def register_hook(self, hook):                                                        │
│    224 │   │   r"""Registers a backward hook.                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│ C:\Users\Mohamed                                                                                 │
│ Amine\Desktop\pytorch_env\torchvenv\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py:130 in backward │
│                                                                                                  │
│   127 │   if retain_graph is None:                                                               │
│   128 │   │   retain_graph = create_graph                                                        │
│   129 │                                                                                          │
│ ❱ 130 │   Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(                                               │
│   131 │   │   tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph,                                │
│   132 │   │   allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag                                  │
│   133                                                                                            │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already 
been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
```

I tried changing the backward call with this but nothing happened

```
            grads = torch.autograd.grad(generator_loss, generator.parameters(), create_graph=True)
            # `grads` is a tuple of gradients for each parameter in `generator`
            # Update the generator parameters
            for i, param in enumerate(generator.parameters()):
                param.grad = grads[i]
```

I tried putting the retain_graph=True for the first backward in the generator and it didn't work also putting retain_graph=True makes the training process slower and resources demanding and I am trying to avoid that.
I read in a thread in Pytorch that putting the loss, the model, and it s complements on the same device solves the error but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I solved it but detaching the fake images when generating the fake predictions for the discriminator loss

```py
            fake_predictions = discriminator(fake_images.detach(), text_embeddings)
            fake_predictions=fake_predictions.to("cpu")
            fake_labels = torch.zeros(fake_images.size(0), 1).to("cpu")
            fake_loss = adversarial_loss(fake_predictions, fake_labels)
```

if someone has a deep understanding of why it did work please explain